Computing Fisher information for a Poisson distribution with any number of events
The context for the question is this paper. I am trying to understand how to get from Eq. (5) to Eq. (7).
For simplicity I will only consider 1 dimension, whereas the equations in the paper are generalised to $D$ dimensions.
Given the probability density
$$ p(t_1,...,t_K|r) = \frac{1}{K!} \prod_{k=1}^K \Gamma(r,t_k)) \exp{\left[-\int_0^{\tau} dt \Gamma(r, t)\right]},$$
the Fisher information about the position $r$ is given by
$$F = \sum_{K=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\tau}dt_t...dt_K\ p(t_1,...,t_K|r)\left(\frac{d}{dr} \ln{p(t_1,...,t_K|r)}\right)^2.$$
I am trying to show that this simplifies to
$$ F = \int_0^{\tau}dt \frac{1}{\Gamma(r, t)}\left(\frac{d}{dr}\Gamma(r, t)\right)^2.$$
The reason I am interested in this is because I would like to derive a Fisher information for a different $p$ (a Gaussian one instead of Poisson).
What I've tried: substituting a specific value of K in the summand and trying to simplify it. This does not seem to help much.
I assume there is some general approach to sums like this that I don't know about. My background is a PhD in Physics but I did not learn very much statistics.
